# sending tun/tap packets to destination server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tun

how can I send the read packet from tun to the server? I checked the packets by Wireshark and all of them was DNS request and changed the default gateway of my system to the IP of my VM and all packets goes there. the tun works good and I can print everything about packets but the problem is I don't know how to forward them to the destination server. (i know socket programming)
the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct sockaddr_in Packet, dest;

#define Tun_Device "tun0"

static int max(int a, int b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
    }

int read_tun(char *name, int type){
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int tun_fd;
    tun_fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = type;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, name, IFNAMSIZ);
    ioctl(tun_fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr);
    return tun_fd;
    }

int main(){ 
    int tun_fd, packet_length, tcpfd;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    char buffer[2048];
    char destination[16];
    int i = 0;
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*) buffer;
    tun_fd = read_tun(Tun_Device, IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI);
    while (1) {
        fd_set readset;
        FD_ZERO(&readset);
        FD_SET(tun_fd, &readset);
        FD_SET( , &readset);
        int max_fd = max(tun_fd, udp_fd) + 1;
        select(max_fd, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        if (FD_ISSET( , &readset)) {
            }

        if (FD_ISSET( , &readset)) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Anyway, I want to clarify, what exactly do you mean by "forward them to the destination server"? You have succeeded to read the packet from TUN device, but you want to send it to the server via socket? Or you want the server forward the packet so your client can have internet connection with server IP address something like VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default gateway must activate IP forwarding and you need to set corresponding iptables rules.

### From gateway machine, you need to:

```
# Turn on IPv4 forward
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Add MASQUERADE rule
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s x.x.x.x/y ! -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

# Allow forwarding
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -d x.x.x.x/y -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -s x.x.x.x/y -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

### Note

- Adjust the `x.x.x.x/y` with your TUN/TAP network subnet.
- Adjust the `tun0` with virtual network interface name you use.

---

### Default Gateway setting for client

You still need to communicate with your internet router when you override any traffic to virtual network interface, because you need to send encapsulated packet to VPN server.

In order to do that, you should not delete your default route that is going via your physical router.

The rule is simple:

- Packet which its destination/source is **VPN server IP address** must be sent/received via physical router.
- Other packets must be sent/received via virtual network interface.
- Plus you may want to make some exceptions for local network if you have any.

### Config example

```
VPN_IFACE=tun0
VPN_PRIVATE_IP=10.8.8.2
VPN_GATEWAY_IP=10.8.8.1
VPN_BROADCAST_IP=10.8.8.25
VPN_PUBLIC_IP=123.123.123.123
REAL_DEFAULT_IP=192.168.1.1

# Raise up virtual network interface
sudo ip link set dev $VPN_IFACE up mtu 1480
sudo ip addr add dev $VPN_IFACE $VPN_PRIVATE_IP/24 broadcast $VPN_BROADCAST_IP

# Encapsulated packet must be routed via your real router.
sudo ip route add $VPN_PUBLIC_IP/32 via $REAL_DEFAULT_IP

# Override any traffic, except for encapsulated packet
# Make them routed via virtual network interface gateway
sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev $VPN_IFACE via $VPN_GATEWAY_IP
sudo ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev $VPN_IFACE via $VPN_GATEWAY_IP

# Don't delete default route to your real physical router!
```

Comment: I doubt this answers the question, I requested a clarification on a comment to the question.

Comment: thanks for anwser. now all packet goes through the tun0 interface. now I'm trying to search in browser but doesn't show anything. it means now i should do socket programming and send each packet to related server? and my second question is how i can get good add network command in Linux?

Comment: I want to create a VPN server. I think first I should get all data from tun and send them to the VPN server and from there to the servers that client wants to connect.

Comment: Yea, you can start socket programming and start using send and recv the packet to forward the TUN/TAP data. I once wrote this to dynamically proceed add network command https://github.com/TeaInside/teavpn2/blob/0.0.1-rc1/src/teavpn2/net/iface.c

Comment: Your server need to `read()` data from TUN/TAP interface, then `send()` it to the client. And then then client calls `recv()` and `write()` the received data to the TUN/TAP interface. The same happens with the opposite direction.

Comment: got it. I am working on it and try to send and recv data. I'll share with you if I had a problem. thanks Ammar.

Comment: Hi. I have some other questions. I'll be glad if you answer them...
Q1: I can't get all packets by the defined interface. if I set the IP address of the interface as the default gateway i can get most of them but I can't send anything to the router. how can I fix this?
Q2: when we send all these packets to the VPN server how can we send TCP packets from the VPN server to the destination servers? we should connect from the VPN server to destination servers by ```connect``` again?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: for more detail for Q2: it's more easier to handle UDP what about TCP packet we should connect to those servers from VPN server using ```connect```?

Comment: @AskingOverFlow I answered Q1 by editing the answer. For Q2, yes if you use TCP then you have to `connect()`.

Comment: you need another route table for your tun interface. about `ip rule` and